# Monitor Enterprise Library Cache

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I want to monitor my Enterprize Libray Cache for memory cosumption, keys and values. I searched stackoverflow and got a [near answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209479/monitoring-enterprise-library-caching). But I don't understand how can I do:

> You can reference the downloaded sourced as a project modify the original CacheManager to expose the instance of cache which has a property called CurrentCacheState.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ICacheManager manager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ICacheManager>("your cache name");
Cache cache = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Cache>("your cache name");
```

You can then do stuff with

```
cache.CurrentCacheState
```